# reverse / inverse bionics?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, technical

Bionics is the application of principles found in nature to design engineering systems.
Which (new) term would be better if we wanted to borrow some principles from technology and apply them in biology: “reverse bionics” or “inverse bionics”? (or maybe other word?)

Comment: **Bioengineering** is a discipline that applies engineering principles of design and analysis to biological systems and biomedical technologies. bioeng.berkeley.edu

Comment: Norman Edward, I need exactly the second word to be added to " bionics"

Comment: With that requirement, _reverse bionics_ sounds "better", for no reason good enough to be an answer.

Comment: Neither term works, as far as I am concerned. The term that does come to mind is extrapolation. You extrapolate from technology and apply them to biology. Hopefully, you don't create a Frankensteinian [adjective mine] universe.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of applying the tech principles in biology? Are you talking about, for example, genetic engineering, or are you (just) trying to use tech language to *describe* biological phenomena?

Comment: I note someone has already voted to close. I do get the feeling that some people on this list are unhappy that technical English exists and feel it has no place on this list because they cannot address it themselves. This is a reasonable question, for which I think there is a clear answer. This, of course, is the one I have given, but then I happen to be involved in technical English.

Comment: This is beginning to look like a fishing expedition for a brand name identity . The functions and combinations already exist - but they are not what he is looking for  -- why?

Comment: @David My question arose because of the need to title a scientific article. No fiction. And I don't understand why anyone would want to close.

Comment: @Lawrence I am talking about genetic engineering. More specific, I am talking about design of logic gates which work according to truth tables and memory cells (they are already created) and some other “devices” (which have not yet been created) in biological objects using genes and interconnections between them.

Comment: @Lawrence — Please do not comment on topics you don't understand on the basis of dictionary definitions. As someone who has been involved in genetic engineering, I can assure you that this is a wide term that may or may not encompass the methods used to achieve what the poster refers to, but is not a description of his specific idea. He is justified in seeking a new term, and my answer explains why he should choose "reverse".

Answer (score 2):

> **Reverse Bionics** is, I suggest, the preferred term if one wishes to be consistent with existing technical usage.

**Reverse and Inverse in everyday English**

Before explaining the technical precedents, it may be helpful for me to consider the different connotations of *reverse* and *inverse* in everyday English. The terms clearly have a variety of meanings, which in some cases overlap (hence the question), but the technical usage seems to have been influenced by the following ‘extremes’:

*reverse:* [‘to move backwards’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reverse)

i.e. a sense of *movement* — from one thing back to another.

*inverse:* [‘Produced from or related to something else by a process of inversion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inverse)

i.e. a sense of *changing position* — turning something upside down, inverting it.

**Technical precedents for *reverse***

This is a question about technical English, so it is pertinent to look at precedents in technical English, even though the subject matter may not be familiar to all. I shall attempt to give simplified explanations.

1. [Reverse Genetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_genetics)

In *classical genetics* one moves *from* an observable change in an organism (different eye colour or other characteristic resulting from an altered *protein*) *to* the gene (region of DNA), the mutation of which has caused the change in the protein. The aim is to identify and locate the particular mutated gene the product of which is responsible for the altered protein.

In *reverse genetics* one starts *from* the knowledge of the DNA of the organism and the deduction of those parts of the DNA that are genes and (by mutating it in the test tube) moves *to* a position where one can identify the protein that gene encodes. Hence the ideas of both movement and reversal.

2. [Reverse Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering)

I am not an engineer, but the idea here would seem to be that normally in *engineering* one moves *from* a design *to* a functional machine (or perhaps software).

In *reverse engineering* one starts *from* the functioning machine and attempts *to* ‘deconstruct’ it to reveal its design (or perhaps its software code).

3. [Reverse Transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_transcriptase)

This is a little more technical, but today’s educated individual should learn to speak molecular biology, rather than Latin. [O tempora, o mores!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_tempora_o_mores!)

The normal direction of *transcription* involves movement of information *from* the sequence of chemical bases in DNA *to* that in a segment of RNA. (This RNA is generally used as a template to make proteins.)

In *reverse transcription* (catalysed by an enzyme entitled ‘reverse transcriptase’) the information *from* the sequence of chemical bases in the RNA of certain viruses (such as HIV) is moved *to* the DNA in the chromosomes of the host (genomic DNA), i.e. in the opposite direction to what had originally been thought the only possibility. (This allows the virus to ‘hide’ in its host, to be released by normal transcription at a suitable time.)

Comment: He reversed his position is not to necessarily move backwards even though it implies it.....

Comment: @Lambie — You are correct. But I have chosen extreme definitions of the two terms (which clearly overlap) to try to explain why one of these has been previously adopted in a technical context.

Comment: I'm afraid that I just can't see this. If you take a set of principles from one field and apply them elsewhere, you are extrapolating.  He is moving between fields. All yours are for the same field. There are  not two fields: biology + technology.)

Comment: @Lambie — Reverse Engineering? How is that Biology? And why cannot one scientific field borrow from another?  If you go to Wikipedia and enter "inverse" in the search box it autocompletes to mainly mathematical terms. You say neither term works for you, but "reverse" is clearly used in the context of physical or conceptual movement. Perhaps "television" doesn't work for you because of its Greek/Latin hybrid origin.

Comment: Are you doing this on purpose or do you not understand my point? reverse engineering [one field], reverse genetics[one field] where a process is reversed within the same field. The OP is talking about taking ONE thing (technology) and putting it PUTTING it THERE (biology). If you reverse engineer a system,  you start from the finished system and work backwards down to the components and finally drawings. He's is not talking about that. I think his question is confused and confusing.

Comment: My only purpose is to help the poster select appropriate technical English. I do not know the details of his ideas, but I can imagine an example. Let us start with an engineering system using graphene, for example. This does not exist in biological systems. That may have some electrical properties that could enhance the ability of bacteria to perform some function useful to man. If the genome of the bacterium was altered to produce graphene in a particular context. This would be reverse bionics. (It would also be [synthetic biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biology).)

Comment: I accept that explanation, of course. However, one would have to have an end-product in an existing bionics universe. Does yours already exist in such a universe? If so, I accept reverse bionics. Of course, inverse is wrong.

Comment: @David Thank you. However, I do realize that my situation differs from such as "reverse engineering" and "reverse transcription". It is more similar to the following a hypothetical example. Usually we gather mushrooms in a basket, and we remove snow by means of a shovel. Suppose someone invented a way to remove snow using a basket and called this way as "method A". Someone another came up with a way to pick mushrooms with a shovel. Is it correct to call it as "reverse method A"? (not taking into account whether this name will be clear without further explanation).

Comment: Definitely not ‘reverse’ in that situation, which seems to me another question entirely. The word ‘reciprocal’ seems much more appropriate to me here, but whether it is right or there is anything better I couldn't say. I'd perhaps post a new question. P.S. You must be Eastern European if you are gathering mushrooms ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, since you are desirous of a "new" term, how about 'techanism'? :)

Comment: Thank you, it is interesting, but I need exactly the second word to be added to " bionics"

Comment: Perhaps 'mechanized bionics'. Seems to flow better than 'technical bionics.